# Getting element properties list (value etc.)

Tags: html, angular, properties

I'm curious how to get all available properties of an element.

An example:

```
<div (click)="getProperties(post)" #post>
 Some content of a post
</div>
```

When I click on the div, I want to get a json with all available properties like value, offsetHeight etc.

```
getProperties(post: any) {
  console.log(post);
}
```

This will print something like that

```
<div _ngcontent...>
  Some content of a post
</div>
```

but I don't want that. I asked few minutes earlier how to get height of div and if I knew how to print all div's properties, I would do that on my own. Now I know that there is somethling like `offsetHeight` but I know that from stackoverflow. Is there some way to print div's properties or API that gives us all of them?

Comment: Basically I created a plunkr for your last post, but till I make it working you had deleted your question, so I'm commenting my working [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IYZVC79aSVNKvsOgeprF?p=preview), Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you and sorry I removed it so fast.

Comment: Np, Basically you could directly do it like I did in plunkr `post.clientHeight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like: post.prototype which will give you both properties and methods. You need to do some filtering on properties.